# Please help me to remove dots only on paragraph and subparagraph numbering

Tags: numbering

I am in need of help, can you please show me how I can remove the dots on the paragraph level and the subparagraph level? Right now, it says aa). bb). 1). 2). and I would like to read aa) bb) 1) 2)
Your help is very much appreciated!

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=oscola,
        backend=biber,
        citepages=suppress,
        ecli=yes,
        babel=hyphen]{biblatex}


\usepackage{enumitem}


\usepackage{alphalph}


\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}


\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}

\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\alph{subsubsection}}

\renewcommand\thesubparagraph{\arabic{subparagraph})}

\makeatletter\newalphalph{\alphMult}[mult]{\@alph}{26}\makeatother

\renewcommand\theparagraph{\alphMult{\value{paragraph} + 26})}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction: Setting the Scene}

\section{ddd}

\subsection{fff}

\subsection{fff}

\subsubsection{ddd}

\subsubsection{ddd}

\paragraph{edd}

\paragraph{edd}

\subparagraph{dd}

\subparagraph{dd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `\paragraphformat` and `\subparagraphformat` to remove `\autodot` and insert `)`:

```latex
\renewcommand*\paragraphformat{\theparagraph)\enskip}
\renewcommand*\subparagraphformat{\thesubparagraph)\enskip}
```

To change the TOC entries you can use

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    tocentrynumberformat=\numendsymbol{)}
  ]{paragraph,subparagraph}
\newcommand*{\numendsymbol}[2]{\def\autodot{#1}#2}
```

If you want to adjust the space for the numbers in TOC you can use:

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    tocnumwidth=1.5em,
    tocdynnumwidth
  ]{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage[style=oscola,
        %backend=biber,
        %citepages=suppress,
        %ecli=yes,
        %babel=hyphen]{biblatex}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\alph{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph{\arabic{subparagraph}}

\makeatletter
\newalphalph{\alphMult}[mult]{\@alph}{26}\makeatother
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\alphMult{\value{paragraph} + 26}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*\paragraphformat{\theparagraph)\enskip}
\renewcommand*\subparagraphformat{\thesubparagraph)\enskip}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    tocentrynumberformat=\numendsymbol{)}
  ]{paragraph,subparagraph}
\newcommand*{\numendsymbol}[2]{\def\autodot{#1}#2}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    tocnumwidth=1.5em,
    tocdynnumwidth
  ]{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subparagraphnumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subparagraphtocdepth}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction: Setting the Scene}
\section{ddd}
\subsection{fff}
\subsection{fff}
\subsubsection{ddd}
\subsubsection{ddd}
\paragraph{edd}
\paragraph{edd}
\subparagraph{dd}
\subparagraph{dd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]